# Simple RegEx Help

Tags: php, regex

Hey guys i have the string:

```
/new/krymson/
```

currently i have the regex:

```
/\/new\//
```

which will remove:

```
/new/
```

How would i include into that regex a way of removing the last `/`?

also the string comes from a url so could be:

```
/new/krymson/admin/interface/modules/
```

or any number of 'keys' after `/new/`.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:
I am using PHP.

I know that this regex `\/$` selects the last `/` in the string but how do i make select the `/new/` and the last `/`?

Comment: In which language are you working? There is almost certainly a better way of achieving this than using regular expressions. In Python: `'/new/krymson/admin/interface/modules/'.split('/')[2]`

Comment: Btw. It helps if you specify the programming or scripting language you use.

Comment: "When asking regex questions, always add the tag for the specific programming language or tool (e.g., Perl, Python, or Java; vi, emacs, or ɢɴᴜ grep; etc.) you are using." --http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Comment: If you are using a language like Perl you can change the regex literal quotes to avoid the leaning-toothpick syndrome (e.g. `m{/new/...}`)). If you are using a language like JavaScript you can use the non-literal form to do the same (e.g. `new RegExp("/new/...")` -- just remember that \'s need to be double to pass through the string literal). Support to change/avoid the need to escape the / will vary by regex provider/language.

Comment: @ChrisWue Scripting languages *are* programming languages -- it's not "Alcohol and drugs" but rather "Alcohol and *other* drugs".

Comment: or would it be easier to just run two regex functions?

Comment: @FraserK - see my post now that we know you're using PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to take a different approach, instead of replacing the stuff i don't want, extract the stuff i do want.

i have finished with this code just for the sake of other people reading this question for help.

```
$string = '/new/krymson/admin/interface/modules/';
$pattern = ' /(?<=\/new\/).*(?=\b)|(?=\/$)/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $match);
$shortened = $match[0];
```

EDIT:

Thanks for all the replies!

Comment: How do you want the regex to handle something like: `/foo/new/krymson/` or maybe even `/foo/new/bar/new/krymson`?

Comment: the full url will look like `yourdomain.com/new/krymson`. `/new/` is only there beacause it is the new build of the site from scratch. so if a user entered /new/foo/krymson it will either return the correct page or a 404

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Now that we know it's PHP another solution is

```
$parts = explode("/", $str);
array_shift($parts);
$str = implode("/", $parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/\/new\/(.*)\//1/
```

The `.*` grabs everything after your first match
The `$` right anchors, so it will get the last `/`

You are replacing the string with the contents of (.*) ... that's language dependent

In perl, for example, it would be:

```
$myString =~ s/\/new\/(.*)\/$\//$1/;
```

**EDIT:** Since we now know we're talking about php:

```
<?php
$string = '/new/krymson/admin/interface/modules/';
$pattern = '/\/new\/(.*)\/$\//';
$replacement = '$1';
$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Comment: I thought * is always greedy - so you should not need the $

Comment: He wanted to get rid of the trailing slash (Edit: Oh, right ... I see what you mean, duh)

Comment: With the anchor the regex engine *may* be able to optimize the regex better. It is also more explicit of the regex's desired intent -- I'd leave it in.

Comment: (Also consider taking advantage of Perl's ability to use different quotes for regex literals ;-)

Comment: @pst - I didn't want to deviate too far from his original example because he didn't state what lang he was using. As for the right-anchor, you're actually correct as anchors almost always increase performance.